# Finding minimum plus maximum of $g(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} |\sin 2x-a\cos x|dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, parametric

Let

> $$g(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} |\sin 2x-a\cos x|dx,\quad a\in[0,1].$$

If $L$ and $M$ are the minimum and maximum values of $g(a)$ for all $a\in [0,1]$. 
Find the value of $L+M$.

The first thing I tried was trying to graph the function. Taking $\cos x$ common from the integrand and out of the modulus as the integral goes from $0$ to $\pi /2$. But after that, how do you treat the parameter $a$ in the integrand? Differentiating $g(a)$ is difficult because there is no clear way of getting rid of the modulus. How do I go about this?

Comment: Off the hat, without trying anything here I'd first try changing whats inside the modulus for a different variable. That would probably make the complexity get out of the modulus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. We have $a \in [0,1]$. Then one may write
$$
\begin{align}
g(a)&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} |\sin 2x-a\cos x|dx
\\\\&=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left|\sin x-\frac{a}2\right|\cos x dx
\\\\&=2\int_{0}^{1}\left|u-\frac{a}2\right|du
\\\\&=2\int_{0}^{a/2}\left(\frac{a}2-u\right)du+2\int_{a/2}^{1}\left(u-\frac{a}2\right)du
\end{align}
$$ giving an *explicit value* of $g(a)$.